# Why Maven cannot process cyclic dependencies, and Java compiler can?

Tags: java, maven, compilation

Imagine we have two classes in our project that depend on each other. I.e. introduce cyclic dependency between classes. These classes can be compiled by Java, of course. If we separate this classes into two different artifacts - Maven cannot compile them. They have a cyclic dependency between artifacts. Why its possible in one artifact and not possible in two? Indeed, its just the same two classes, no matter in which folders they reside.

But there is something deeper I dont get I suppose..

?

Comment: Nothing deeper. Java resolves cyclic dependencies only if done in a single compilation run. So does Maven - fwiw, its just a wrapper around javac.

Comment: I would argue that maven does not want to do that. Running in cycles does bring you far away :) It is often better to have a linear deployment path. So a tree is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate artifacts - this means you have 2 different libraries.
You should build one library, then build another dependent library.
You cannot build artifact before you built it's dependency.
This is just rules for artifacts. Each artifact is built in separate step.

When you build 2 dependent classes in one library - you haven't any limitations like this, you can compile several classes at one step.